# Is PA consistent? do we know it?

Tags: foundations, lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy, peano-arithmetic, induction

1) (By Goedel's) One can not prove, in PA, a formula that can be interpreted to express the consistency of PA. (Hopefully I said it right. Specialists correct me, please).
2) There are proofs (although for the purpose of this question I should putt it in quotations marks) of the consistency of PA.

The **questions** are: 
A) Is it the consistency of PA still a mathematical question that can be considered open?
B) Is it a mathematical question? (To this I dare to say that it is a mathematical question. Goedel himself translated it into a specific formula, but then I have question C)
C) Is it accepting the proofs of the consistency of PA as conclusive a mathematically justified act or an act of taking a philosophical stance?

**Motivation:** There is a discussion in the mailing list [FOM](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/mailman/listinfo/fom/) (Foundations Of Mathematics) about this topic, in part motivated by this talk [link text](http://video.ias.edu/voevodsky-80th) . I thought a discussion about this fundamental matter concerns most mathematicians and wanted to bring it to a wider audience.

**Edit:** It is simple. Either: 
1) Consistency of PA is proved and has a proof (as claimed by some in FOM) as valid as any other theorem in math, or
2) On top of the existing proofs a philosophic choice is needed (which explains the length of the discussions in FOM, justifies closing this question but contradicts what is being claimed emphatically by some in FOM)

But you see. If 1) is the case then there is no need for the lengthy discussions and this is a concrete math question as any other, terminating with a proof.

........................................................................................

**Edit 2:** Thank you all. Although I had seen some of these arguments at FOM now I think I have my ideas more organized and I can make my question more concrete. I would like to try to put aside what involves 'believes'. In, I think, all the answers shown there has been this action entering the argument quite soon, e.g. In Chow's: (approx.) If you believe in the existence of the naturals then con(PA) follows. In Friedman's (approx.) If you believe in (About a dozen Basic axioms) + (1/n subsequences) then con(PA) follows.

I want to put aside that initial action because (1): It is a philosophical question and that is not what I want to discuss, (2): Because of: If I believe (propositional logic) + (p/-p) then I believe ... for example (everything you can say) and maybe (3): Because I, personally, don't do math to believe what I prove. When I show P->Q, in a sequence of self imposed constrained steps I don't do it with the purpose of showing that, and at the end I don't have a complete conviction that, Q is a property of whatever could be a real world. But that is just philosophy and philosophy allows for any sort of choices. That is why I want to put it aside, at least until the moment in which it is inevitably needed.

**My question is:** Is any of the systems that prove con(PA) a system that has itself been proven consistent?

Why to ask this question? Regardless of how your feelings are about the ontological nature of what you prove. We can say that, since an inconsistent system proves everything, a consistent system is a bit more interesting for not doing so. At least if it is because there is not always a proof in which you use modus ponens twice (after you have found p/-p) for everything that you want to prove.

I guess that also, to answer the question above, it should be clarified what to accept for a consistency proof. Let's leave it kind of open and just try to delay the need for a philosophic stance as much as possible.

Comment: Have you seen en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen's_consistency_proof ? (And do you believe in induction up to $\epsilon_0$?) 

Comment: Given the rather lengthy debate on FOM, and the fact that MO is not for debates or discussions, I don't know that this question is a good fit.  Although if someone posts a contradiction in PA I guess that would give a definite answer...

Comment: The standard proofs of the consistency of PA use the same kinds of methods used to prove results throughout mathematics. So why are you singling out these particular proofs as worthy of special attention?

Comment: @Gubkin: But that is precisely what puzzles me. If it is a settled question. Why is there such a long debate? 

Comment: I have voted to close, even though I think this is an interesting question, because, as Franklin points out, there is extensive and impassioned discussion on a mailing list already, and that is a far better forum than MO for this discussion.

Comment: And, in addition, the moderators of FOM has said that he will not post any more mailings about the Con(PA) debate unless they add something new. MO is not the place to continue fruitless discussion.

Comment: I would vote to close if possible (lack of reputation) for te same reasons mentioned by David Roberts and the tone of Mirco's response which I fear would be endemic if this question stayed open.

Comment: Especially after reading (Matthew) Emerton's long and cogent message on meta, I've decided to cast the last reopening vote. But I please remind everyone to "keep a civil tongue" -- respond coolly and factually. 

Comment: Dear Franklin, Regarding your second edit: the difficulty with removing the notion of "belief" from the discussion is that no-one can write down in finite time all the possible deductions from the axioms of PA; indeed since PA has infinitely many axioms, no-one can even write down all the axioms.  So when we make an argument for consistency (or so it seems to me) we have to invoke *some* other underlying structure so as to have something to build on; if a person doesn't believe in that structure, they then won't believe the consistency proof.  Clearly, Voevodsky does not believe that ... 

Comment: ... arbitrary formulas in PA give rise to well-defined subsets of $\mathbb N$, and so Timothy Chow's consistency proof carries no weight with him.  I think the situation is something like this: if a contradiction is derived, and carefully checked, we can all be sure that it is there, and that PA is inconsistent.  But the assertion that *no contradicition will ever be derived* in PA is not amenable to direct checking, and so *some* conceptual infrastructure (i.e. some beliefs) are necessary if one wants to convince oneself that this assertion is true.  Regards, Matthew

Comment: Meta thread is at:
$$ $$
http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1057/is-pa-consistent-do-we-know-it 
$$ $$


Comment: related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40920 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41217

Comment: In my humble opinion it is intuitively obvious that any reasonable formalization of mathematics, or even of arithmetic, is bound to be inconsistent. 

Comment: @Pierre-Yves: did you really mean to say 'inconsistent' instead of 'consistent'? If so, what would an *unreasonable* formalization be like? And either way: how is it 'intuitively obvious'? 

Comment: @Todd Trimble - Thanks for your comment! I did mean inconsistent. (I added the word “reasonable” by precaution: otherwise one could take any theory that is consistent for trivial reasons and call it a formalization of arithmetic.) To be really convincing, a “proof” of consistency of a given formalization of arithmetic should be (in my opinion) purely syntactic, and forbid any use of the intuitive (semantic) interpretation of the formulas. I think if one adopts such a syntactic standpoint, it’s hard to believe in the consistency of any serious mathematical theory. 

Comment: @Todd Trimble - Let me try to give a more concrete illustration of my previous comment. In Bourbaki’s set theory, a set is by definition a term of the theory. In our interpretation, each term corresponds to a given “object”, and we interpret a theorem of the form A=B as meaning that A and B describe the “same” object. Even Bourbaki makes the confusion when he defines a singleton as being a set with exactly one element. The correct definition would be: it’s a nonempty set all of whose elements are equal.

Answer (score 49):

**EDIT:** I have written a [paper](http://alum.mit.edu/www/tchow/consistent.pdf) that greatly expands on my answer here, and that in particular contains sketches of Gentzen's proof and Friedman's proof, as well as a discussion of formalism.

---

I have already posted an answer but in light of the discussion and the kinds of confusions that have emerged, I believe that this additional answer will be helpful.

Let us first note that the consistency of PA, or more precisely a certain formalized version of it that I will call "Con(PA)," is a theorem of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (ZF).  Conceptually, the simplest ZF proof is obtained by formalizing the easy and almost trivial argument that N, the natural numbers, is a model of PA.

ZF is an extremely powerful system, and the full power of ZF is not needed for proving Con(PA).  Famously, Gentzen showed that primitive recursive arithmetic (PRA), a very weak system, can prove Con(PA) if you add the ability to do induction up to the countable ordinal $\epsilon_0$.  Other ways to prove Con(PA) are available.  Let B-W denote the statement that "every bounded sequence of rational numbers contains a subsequence $(q_i)$ such that for all $n$, $|q_i - q_j| < 1/n$ for all $i, j > n$."  Then B-W implies every axiom of PA, and this implication can be proven in the system RCA$_0$, yielding a relative consistency proof.  Moreover, according to Harvey Friedman, RCA$_0$ can be replaced by a theory deriving from the program of SRM (strict reverse mathematics).

Most mathematical statements are no longer considered "open problems" once a proof has been published or otherwise made widely available, and checked and confirmed by experts to be correct.  Note that published proofs, and expert verification, usually make no explicit reference to any particular underlying formal system such as ZF or PRA.  Mathematicians are trained to recognize correct proofs when they see them, even if no set of axioms is explicitly specified.  If pressed to specify an axiomatic system, a common choice is ZF, or ZFC (ZF plus the axiom of choice).  If a proof is available that is explicitly formalizable in ZF, that is normally regarded as more than sufficient for settling an assertion and removing its "open problem" status.

In the case of Con(PA), the aforementioned "normal conditions" for removing its "open problem" status have been met, and in fact exceeded.  Nevertheless, some debate continues over its status, most likely because Con(PA) is widely perceived to be a somewhat unusual mathematical statement, having connections to philosophical questions in the foundations of mathematics.  For example, some people, whom I will loosely call "formalists" or "ultrafinitists," maintain that many ordinary mathematical statements (e.g., "every differentiable function is continuous") have no concrete meaning, and the only concrete thing that can be said about them is whether they can or cannot be proved in this or that formal system; however, a statement such as "PA is consistent" *is* regarded as having a direct, concrete meaning.  Roughly speaking this is because "PA is inconsistent," unlike infinitary mathematical statements, can be assigned a quasi-physical meaning as the existence of a certain finite sequence of symbols that we can physically apprehend.  While the formalist agrees with all the above facts about the provability of Con(PA) in this or that formal system, such formal proofs don't necessarily carry any weight with the formalist as far as establishing the consistency of PA (in what I've called the "quasi-physical" sense) goes.  Formalists will generally agree that explicitly exhibiting a contradiction in PA will definitively establish its *inconsistency*, but may differ regarding what, if anything, would definitively establish its *consistency*.

There are others who are not formalists but who reject the commonly accepted standard of ZF(C) and only accept proofs that are formalizable in much weaker systems.  For example, someone with strong constructivist leanings might only accept proofs that are formalizable in RCA$_0$.  For such a person, the proof of Con(PA) in ZF carries no weight.  Roughly speaking, the usual ZF proof, that proceeds by showing that N is a model of the axioms of PA, assumes that any first-order formula defines a set of natural numbers, and this assumption is unprovable on the basis of RCA$_0$ alone.  In fact, one can prove that Con(PA) is *unprovable* in RCA$_0$.  Such a person might regard the consistency of PA as permanently unknowable (in a way similar to those who regard the continuum hypothesis as permanently unknowable since it has been proved independent of ZFC).  Note, by the way, that this person would also regard a sizable portion of generally-accepted mathematics (including Brouwer's fixed-point theorem, the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, etc.) as being "unproved" or "unprovable."

To summarize, the consistency of PA is not an open problem in the usual sense of the term "open problem."  Some people do nevertheless assert that it is an open problem, or that it has not been proven.  When you encounter such an assertion, you should be aware that most likely, the person is using the term "open problem" in a somewhat nonstandard fashion, and/or holds to certain standards of proof that are more stringent than those that are commonly accepted in the mathematical community.

Finally, to answer the new question that Franklin has asked, about whether the consistency of any of the systems in which Con(PA) has been proved has been proved: The answer is, "not in any sense that you would likely find satisfying."  For example, one can "prove" that PRA + induction up to $\epsilon_0$ is consistent, in the sense that the consistency proof can be formalized in ZF, which as I said above is the usual standard for settling mathematical questions.  If, however, the reason that you're asking the question is that you *doubt* the consistency of PA, and are hoping that you can settle those doubts by proving the consistency of PA in some "weaker" system that can then be proved consistent using "weaker" assumptions that you don't have any doubts about, then you're basically out of luck.  This, roughly speaking, was Hilbert's program for eliminating doubts about the consistency of infinitary set theory.  The hope was that one could prove the consistency of (say) ZF on the basis of a weak system such as (say) PRA, about which we had no doubts.  But Goedel showed that not only is this impossible, but even if we allow all of ZF into our arsenal, we *still* can't prove the consistency of ZF.  For better or for worse, this tempting road out of skepticism about consistency is intrinsically blocked.

Comment: Following up on the last paragraph: this is in no way unique to Con(PA). We know in an informal and somewhat trivial way that "to prove a theorem you have to make assumptions at least as strong as the conclusion." This is reflected formally in the Lindenbaum algebra of each formal theory. It is reflected philosophically in the debate whether mathematical truth is analytic. In this sense every mathematical proof (of a non-logical validity) is circular. This is noticed most often in the context of consistency proofs but I do not see them as special in this way.

Comment: "(according to Harvey Friedman) actually much less than RCA0 is needed." Can someone ask him to please write this down/up? This is too interesting a result to lurk as claims in fom postings and as hearsay by others in other internet forums.

Comment: In FOM posts http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2015-May/018744.html and http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2015-May/018752.html Friedman has said that he has the best of intentions to write this stuff up Real Soon Now.

Comment: Here is one other relevant FOM post by Harvey Friedman: https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-May/015477.html

Comment: "B-W implies Con(PA)" Does this mean that B-W is false in certain non-standard models of arithmetic?

Comment: @PyRulez : Yes, B-W is false in certain non-standard models of arithmetic. Simpson's book "Subsystems of Second-Order Arithmetic" is the standard reference for this kind of thing.

Comment: @TimothyChow I notice Harvey has gone silent on the fom mailing list. I guess he is working hard at finishing writing up stuff he's been claiming recently... (Also, to make this relevant: I hope he is closer to writing the proof alluded to earlier in the comments)

Answer (score 30):

As Mirco Mannucci's answer suggests, the alternatives labeled 1) and 2) in the question are (for some people) not mutually exclusive.  The consistency of PA indeed "has a proof as valid as any other theorem in math" (as Timothy Chow's answer pretty much shows) --- alternative 1.  Nevertheless, if one doesn't believe the integers exist, then the bottom drops out from that and also from almost everything else in math.  So to be really convinced by the proof, one makes a philosophical choice to accept the existence of integers and the meaningfulness of quantification over them.  What strikes me as strange is that people who have made that choice (or at least act as if they had made it) and are perfectly content with theorems that rely on the availability not just of integers but of far more complex entities (real numbers, sets thereof, etc.) suddenly develop philosophical qualms about such reliance when used to prove the consistency of PA.

Let me also comment on Gentzen's proof.  Note that Timothy didn't invoke that argument but gave instead a much more natural and understandable proof.  So what is Gentzen's proof good for?  As far as I can see, its primary value from a philosophical point of view is that it can be used if one doesn't accept arbitrary first-order sentences about the integers (with possibly lots of quantifiers) as meaningful.  The induction axiom scheme of PA says that such sentences can be proved by induction (ordinary induction on natural numbers), which is true but presupposes that these sentences are meaningful.  Gentzen's proof uses induction on ordinal numbers up to $\varepsilon_0$ but only to prove very simple, finitary statements.  (His proof can be formalized in the system PRA of primitive recursive arithmetic plus the assumption that there is no primitive recursive decreasing sequence of ordinals below $\varepsilon_0$.)  The upshot is that there's a trade-off: If you want to prove the consistency of PA by induction on only extremely simple statements, then you need a long induction, of length $\varepsilon_0$.

Comment: Andreas, yes, if someone doubts that natural numbers exist, almost everything else in math also drops out, at least as far as ontological beliefs go. But that does not mean that the skeptic fellow will stop loving and/or doing math, or worse, act as a censor and try to obliterate some of its branches, such as for instance set theory. I do not believe in the number 5, yet I am fascinated by the theory of extremely large cardinals. To me, that is another gorgeous game with precise syntactic rules, and some folks play it well and build excellent works of art in Cantor paradise

Comment: "...suddenly develop philosophical qualms..." So you don't suddenly develop an increased attention to rigor when doing math, as opposed to the rest of your daily life. For this reason you never use any medicine (because its action hasn't been proved), never attend seminars (because it hasn't been proved that the talks will run as scheduled), etc. I see. Well, I'm proving my theorems only to better understand world; so I feel comfortable using induction because I'm confident that it's at least very, very close to being true, and any potential problems with PA will not change my proofs too much.

Comment: @Sergey: The position you seem to be defending, being uncertain about mathematics in the same sense (though less intensely) as about "real life", seems coherent to me.  What I consider strange, though, is to accept some parts of mathematics (e.g., real analysis) without expressing any doubts, while expressing doubts, based on ontological issues (doubts whether the integers exist), about statements like Con(PA) that seem to require far less ontological commitment than real analysis.  The analog in your real-life examples would be someone who is ... (continued in next comment)

Comment: (continuation of previous comment) confident that next week's seminars will take place as scheduled and that his medicine will continue to work but has serious doubts about whether the sun will rise tomorrow.

Comment: Dear Andreas, Regarding the issue that "strikes [you] as strange": 
after listening to Voevodsky's lecture, my impression is the following: while he (and most mathematicians) work with concepts much more complex than PA, on the other hand, in practice they only use rather limited examples of comprehension, i.e. the formulas they work with are typically of a very limited kind.   Voevodsky's position seems to be a strongly constructivist one, and it is not the level of complexity of objects that he seems to be rejecting, but rather non-constructive assertions about them.   I think that ...

Comment: ... this point of view might be hard to formalize with standard foundations (because it might be hard to distinguish formally between the concrete formulas which one admits as having a meaning, and the more general formulas which one rejects as meaningless), and this is in part motivating Voevodsky's attempts to develop new foundations.
(I am speaking as an interested non-expert here, and I apologize if I'm blundering in my analysis of the situation.)  Regards, Matthew

Comment: Andreas, I was trying to say a bit more in my previous comment: just like in daily life we are sometimes forced to trust things that are not entirely certain (just in order to survive), in math we're often forced to base our work on assumptions stronger than we'd like to (just in order to produce *any* results at all); so it's a little strange to deny the right to doubt Con(PA) to somebody who has once used large cardinals to prove determinacy of projective games.
Todd Trimble's answer (especially in his footnote 2) now elaborates on this point better than I would be able to (hence my delay).

Comment: (cont'd) In particular, it's not a crime, I think, but rather an issue to be aware of, that, if I'm getting it right, Martin-Lof type theory with universes (as in his 1984 book) proves Con(PA) and much more than that (see http://www.jstor.org/pss/20118649 and other papers by Michael Rathjen and Anton Setzer), whereas Voevodsky certainly needs universes (many universes?) for his foundations project. Without universes, however, the Martin-Lof type theory admits a "consistency proof by finitary methods", see Jan M. Smith, http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.48.8077


Answer (score 23):

For some reason, this question generates more confusion than it really should.  My belief is that if you understand the question properly, then you should be able to answer it yourself.

So let me ask the following question: Suppose $P(n)$ asserts a mathematical property of the nonnegative integer $n$, and suppose we can prove $P(0)$ and we can also prove that for all $n$, $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$.  Does $P(n)$ hold for all $n$?

This is just mathematical induction, and the answer is so obviously yes that you must wonder if it's a trick question.  But I'm not asking a trick question.  The answer is yes.

Now let me ask if a first-order formula in the language of arithmetic (e.g., $\exists y: y+y=x$) defines a mathematical property of the integers.  Again, the answer is so obviously yes that you must wonder if it's a trick question.  But it's not a trick question.  The answer is yes.

If you're with me so far, then you have just agreed that PA is consistent.  You should now be able to ask yourself, did you make any philosophical assumptions just now?  Is the validity of mathematical induction a philosophical question or a mathematical one?  If it's a mathematical question, is it still an open problem?

Comment: There is something I didn't understand. Answering yes to both questions is the act of assuming induction (taking it as an axiom and using it). How does that answer the question of whether taking different P's and using induction with them you never get the formula Q/\-Q for some Q?

Making a set (an entity that encapsulates in some way) all the elements satisfying a property is as intuitively obvious and acceptable as assuming induction, except for the fact that if you do it carelessly it is not difficult to create Q/\-Q.

(continued in a second comment)

Comment: Now, Gentzen's proof, or any other. Very naively, induction up to $\epsilon_0$ implies Con(PA). But again, if from assuming that induction you can get Q/\-Q then you can get anything and in particular Con(PA). That is why I don't understand in what sense is that a proof. It is indeed a proof that induction up to $\epsilon_0$ implies Con(PA) but to get Con(PA) you have to get settle down the induction first. 

What I get from the discussion is that something is wrong in what I said. What is it I would like to know?

Comment: The question of whether every formula with one free variable determines a property is exactly what has to be proved. The failure of this is exactly what goes wrong in naive set theory with expressions such as $\{ x: x \not \in x\}$.  However, we have two completely different proofs of consistency: Gentzen's and Goedel's. These show that, in fact, formulas of PA do determine sensible predicates, at least in the sense that the axiom scheme of induction is consistent. 

Comment: The failure of formulas to do sensible things is also what enables Curry's paradox that shows that certain type theories stronger than PA are inconsistent. It seems odd, but somehow the second-order induction axiom seems less worrisome in this way than the first-order axiom scheme. 

Comment: @Mummert: I agree that that is exactly what went wrong in naive set theory, but there is a step from there to say that that is exactly what has to be proved. Do you mean that the origin of paradoxes is this *and only this*? Has that been isolated as such? 

Comment: @Franklin: I was responding directly to Timothy Chow's post. It seems virtually all mathematicians feel the *semantic* concept of natural numbers is consistent; in this sense we only need to worry whether the syntactic aspects of PA could somehow be inconsistent. Our concept of $\mathbb{N}$ validates the basic axioms of $PA^{-}$ and the second-order induction scheme, just as Timothy Chow says. That leaves the question whether the first order induction scheme is true in $\mathbb{N}$. To prove this it would be enough to show every formula of PA with one free variable defines a set of numbers. 

Comment: ... That is not how the actual consistency proofs go, but it is what Timothy Chow invokes in the fourth paragraph of his answer. I think this is really the heart of the consistency question.

Comment: @Franklin: Under the assumption that first-order formulas define mathematical properties, it follows that if you were to get Q /\ -Q then the natural numbers would both have a mathematical property and not have it.  For example, the square root of 2 would be simultaneously rational and irrational.

Comment: @Chow: You realize that "define mathematical properties" would be a proof only if you were to take N as an existing entity for which you can experimentally check the each property for all of it? 

I will repeat your "proof" with a different universe to see what we get. Take a chessboard an a Queen on it (on the first row). That's one axiom. The inference rule: The movement of the queen. Let's say the first four rows are True and the last four are its negations. This system proves all its formulas. Your are saying that from the existence of the board and the label True of False you (continued)

Comment: get the consistency of it. Notice that I will not allow you to check that with four moves you can reach a contradiction as you are not doing that with the naturals. You are pleased just with stating its existence.

Comment: @Franklin: Your definition of proof runs counter to normal mathematical standards for proof. E.g., mathematicians regard it as proved (not an open problem) that every differentiable function is continuous, even though there's no way to "experimentally check" an uncountable number of differentiable functions at uncountably many points for continuity. By normal mathematical standards, PA is provably consistent. You can of course introduce unconventional philosophical standards and declare that the consistency of PA is an open problem, but then you shouldn't be surprised if people argue with you.

Comment: Timothy: I was taught in middle school that "normal mathematical standards" involve fixing the axioms, since Euclid. You can have your default set of axioms: ZFC, ZF, PA or whatever (over a default choice of first order logic, etc., as I was taught in university) which you can then assume implicitly in all your assertions, including "differentiability implies continuity". But you seem to be saying that you got so accustomed to your default choice that you simply dismiss any axioms as a ridicule. This sounds more like the normal standards of mathematical physics or just as falling standards.

Comment: @Sergey: No, I'm not dismissing anything. You can fix ZFC or MK or NBG or any of a variety of systems if you want to; the proof I sketched goes through in any of them, as do at least 99.9% all normal mathematical proofs. Since virtually all math goes through in any of these systems, we don't normally bother to specify any particular one of them. (John Conway refers to this attitude as the "Mathematicians' Liberation Movement.") However, if you want to specify a weak system like PA or PRA as your base, then you need to say so, because doing so throws some ordinary mathematics out the window.

Comment: Timothy: So when you're saying "By normal mathematical standards, PA is provably consistent" it should be taken to mean that that the consistency of PA is provable in "ZFC or MK or NBG"? Then what about the consistency of those? It's still harder to prove. What you're saying is like this: suppose that someone proved that the Riemann hypothesis is implied by P$\ne$NP. Now everybody believes that P$\ne$NP, so "by normal standards" the Riemann Hypothesis is proved. I would argue that it would only be proved by the standards of that community that *believes* that P$\ne$NP in a religious sense.

Comment: (cont'd) Similarly, PA is provably consistent by the standards of the community that *believes* ZFC or even Morse-Kelley or at least second order arithmetic in a religious sense. It might be that this community is quite large, but it does not include all mathematicians; for instance, I'm a counterexample. By contrast, there do seem to be certain "normal mathematical standards", essentially unchanged since Euclid, that indeed 100% mathematicians do accept. I maintain that by these standards PA has not been proved to be consistent.

Comment: No, by normal mathematical standards, I mean ones that virtually all mathematicians accept. Recall that *you* were the one who introduced specific axiomatic systems into the discussion, not me. For example, as Friedman has pointed out, the consistency of PA follows from the following assertion: "Every bounded sequence of rational numbers contains a subsequence (q_i) such that for all n, |q_i - q_j| < 1/n for all i,j > n." Do you accept that assertion?  It's easily provable by methods taught in undergraduate analysis. If so, then the consistency of PA follows by reasoning formalizable in RCA_0.

Comment: I don't see why I should accept or reject some assertions in an absolute sense. Is it a game you want me to play with you? In fact I don't understand the meaning of your "accept". It's not a mathematical notion but a philosophical one. If you care about my philosophy in this respect, look up "ignosticism" at Wikipedia; you could then ask yourself if the assertion about bounded sequences is falsifiable. I'm far less comfortable with $RCA_0$ and with quantification over all (which all?) bounded sequences than with the induction schema of PA. What Emerton says about it also makes sense to me.

Comment: @Sergey: You used the word "accept" yourself in your previous comment ("100% mathematicians do accept"). What did you mean when you said that? I thought you meant it in a mathematical sense. There is a simple mathematical proof of the assertion I made. We iterate the following process: Subdivide the current interval into finitely many subintervals of length < 1/n. Pick a subinterval that has infinitely many numbers remaining in it, and pick some number q_n in it. If I were to give this lecture in an undergraduate analysis course, no mathematician I know would object to this proof. Do you?

Comment: Timothy, 1) I was talking about one's acceptance of "normal mathematical standards", and that couldn't possibly be a mathematical notion, because "normal mathematical standards" are themselves, at best, a meta-mathematical notion (it was not me who introduced it here). My intended meaning was mundane: something you accept or not as a tool in your own daily work. This meaning doesn't seem to apply to your assertion about bounded sequences. 2) I do object to your proof because it's not clear what you mean by it. You first said you're "not dismissing" axioms, but when I tried to make you specify

Comment: ...the formal system you're assuming for the purpose of the present discussion, you seemed to revert to a non-axiomatic position. So I'm now completely confused on your assumptions for the above proof. I also think that an undergraduate with an interest in foundations listening to your Calculus course might have a valid concern about your background assumptions, and if you'd reply him in the spirit of your answer here and subsequent comments, he would rightly think that you're misleading him into sophisms and mantras instead of a serious answer.

Comment: @Sergey: I am just trying to understand what you would regard as a proof of the consistency of PA by "normal mathematical standards that 100% of mathematicians do indeed accept." Apparently, even if Con(PA) were provable in RCA_0 (which it can't be), that wouldn't be good enough. So I tried giving a specific mathematical proof, to see whether it's an example of something that you would agree that 100% of mathematicians would accept. Sociologically, I think at least 99.9%, of mathematicians would accept it, without demanding that any axiomatic system be specified. But you're in the 0.1%.  So...

Comment: ...I am left wondering just what those "normal mathematical standards that 100% of mathematicians do indeed accept" are. Can you say explicitly what they are?  Or at least, can you give an example of a theorem that has been proven according to these standards?  "There are infinitely many primes," perhaps?  "The square root of 2 is irrational"?  Or do all examples have to be of the form, "`There are infinitely many primes' is a theorem of ZF"?

Comment: Yes they do have to be of this form! I think I've been answering your questions diligently but you haven't yet specified if your "proof" has to be understood as being in ZF or where, and still want me to say something about this proof. By the way, your 99.9% figure seems to be bogus: I think the present thread, and the fact that Emerton's answer has been upvoted above yours (at the moment) even though it appeared later shows it clearly. In fact I don't think that the numbers could be so terrible even among freshmen in a small university. 

Comment: @Sergey: are you saying you do not accept the statement "there are infinitely many primes", only "ZFC proves there are infinitely many primes"? What about the statement "there are infinitely many natural numbers" - is that only "provable in ZFC"?  If you are arguing that one cannot assert these statements themselves, I think you are indeed among a very small minority of mathematicians. Most mathematicians accept "there are infinitely many primes" as true independent of any formal system. In fact the ability to prove statements like this is a test and requirement of any proposed formal system. 

Comment: "Can you say explicitly what they are?" OK I see, "they are essentially unchanged since Euclid" was only an implicit answer. Explicitly: in my opinion, virtually nobody rejects a correct proof of a theorem whose statement either explicitly or implicitly specifies all the assumptions made (e.g. in the form of a first order theory). "Theorems" that remain *deliberately* vague about the ground axioms seem to be acceptable to some (al-Khwarizmi, Euler, Arnold) and unacceptable to others (Euclid, Hilbert, Bourbaki). This is not a matter of 0.1% or ultrafinitists as you're trying to present.

Comment: Carl: I see no problem with *asserting* these statements, discussing  their meaning, and using them as a test for assessing practical value of formal systems. But I don't see why I should *accept* them. If it turns out that PA is contradictory and there's only a finite amount of information in the physical universe, they may have to be corrected in a nontrivial way. If you're sometimes using Newton's gravity law where it applies, should you be forced to *accept* it universally? And your "very small minority" amuses me: how do you explain the votes on this page? Any "proof" of "very small"???

Comment: @Sergey: I don't think online forums generally give accurate samples of mathematicians' beliefs. Online discussions routinely overstate the doubt about such things as the consistency of PA, the truth of the axiom of choice, etc.  If we examine textbooks, which are written much more deliberately than online discussions, we see that with only very rare exceptions they accept the consistency of PA (and the axiom of choice).  For example, I have seen dozens of textbooks prove "there are infinitely many primes" and none phrased it as "if ZFC is consistent then there are infinitely many primes."

Comment: Carl: here is a more specific answer to your question on infinitely many primes versus ZFC. My answer consists of 4 questions to you: 1) are you familiar with the work of Parikh and Sazonov? 2) Do you know of an error in, say, Sazonov's paper 'On feasible numbers'? 3) Do you know of any result in mathematics or any physically observable fact that would show that what you refer to as integers satisfy Peano's axioms, and not Sazonov's axioms (perhaps after some scaling)? 4) Is your preference of Peano's axioms over Sazonov's due to purely aesthetic reasons, or you have other reasons as well?

Comment: Carl: I don't find the textbook argument convincing, because it's incredibly more difficult to do anything without PA than with it, and why would one mention her doubts about Con(PA) in a book if she can't add anything substantial to those doubts? And I'm reading books in a different way: unless the author explicitly discusses this issue, I'm reading every theorem so that it omits mentioning the axioms of ZFC or something like that (just to make the reading more enjoyable) which axioms it nevertheless implicitly assumes. 

Comment: @Sergey: If I understand you correctly, it is intrinsically impossible to prove a statement such as "there are infinitely many primes" by standards that 100% of mathematicians would accept, simply because that statement is syntactically not of the form "X is provable in formal system S."  So when you claim that "PA is consistent" has not been proved by those standards, it has nothing to do with PA specifically, but just with the trivial fact that the sentence "PA is consistent" does not have the syntactic form "X is provable in formal system S." Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know. At least people who call themselves formalists should accept no other standards.

Comment: @Sergey: O.K., I think I finally understand. I think, though, that you have expressed yourself in a very misleading manner. Earlier you said, `there do seem to be certain "normal mathematical standards", essentially unchanged since Euclid, that indeed 100% mathematicians do accept. I maintain that by these standards PA has not been proved to be consistent.' This makes it sound like there is something special about PA. In fact, you also maintain that by these standards, the square root of 2 has not been proved to be irrational. Had you said this earlier, your meaning would have been clearer.

Comment: As an aside, I do not think that this was what Franklin was asking about.  I do not think he would ever consider posting an MO question saying, "Is the square root of 2 irrational?  Do we know it?"

Comment: Timothy: when you're saying "the square root of 2 has not been proved to be irrational", it is an ambiguous sentence: the obvious meaning is "... in ZFC", but you are asking your reader to ascribe to me the highly non-obvious meaning, "... assuming no hypotheses whatsoever".
In contrast, "PA has not been proved to be consistent" has no obvious meaning, because "... in ZFC" is silly; but in the context of your answer above the obvious meaning was "... assuming no hypotheses whatsoever".

Comment: I now seem to see the problem with your answer: Con(PA) is indeed a rather special assertion if compared with "usual mathematics", not in that we "suddenly develop philosophical qualms" and apply different standards to its proof, but in that its *subconscious default reading* (at least for some people) is unusual - I guess since Hilbert's program rather than since your answer. Your answer then seems to be about linguistics and psychology, and not even remotely about mathematics. I think I'm going to elaborate this into a separate answer now.

Comment: Dear Timothy and Sergey, I don't see how one can really compare Con(PA) to irrationality of the square root of two.  The latter is demonstrably irrational in a completely constructive manner, and so surely is believed in some absolute sense by more people than those who believe in an absolute sense in Con(PA).    I think the difference between constructive and non-constructive proofs is particularly relevant both for foundational questions in general, and for a discussion precipitated by Voevodsky's lecture, in particular. Regards, Matthew

Comment: @Emerton: What Sergey and I are talking about is the *meaning* of "PA is consistent" versus the *meaning* of "the square root of 2 is irrational." For Sergey, "PA is consistent" has a concrete *meaning*, but "the square root of 2 is irrational" does not. This has nothing to do with what it takes to *prove* either assertion. @Sergey: If you read my answer not with your personal "subconscious default reading" but reading "PA is consistent" in the same way you would read "the square root of 2 is irrational" then you will (or should) see that my answer is entirely mathematical.

Comment: What I don't understand is, if someone doubts that integers exist, then what does "PA is consistent" mean to him? Does it make sense to imagine that **integers** don't exist, but **formal proofs** do exist? Does anybody think that "there is no proof of 0 = 1 in PA" is a meaningful assertion which must be either true or false, but "there are no odd perfect numbers" is meaningless formalism?

Answer (score 14):

Here is an attempt to answer the question that I posted on the meta discussion, and which I am reposting here now that the question has been reopened. [Note: I am a non-expert with an interest in foundational issues, and I am doing my best to understand the situation. I 
hope that my lack of technical expertise in the area has not led to too many stupidities,
and welcome any such being pointed out.]

---

The question is asked not in isolation, but in the context of a lecture by Voevodsky. This can (and probably should) inform the answer, and will certainly inform my answer.

Now, as Timothy Chow notes in his answer here (and in his posts on the FOM mailing list), if one accepts the existence of the natural numbers, and of arbitrary subsets of the natural numbers, then one can prove that PA is consistent, by exhibiting its standard model, namely the natural numbers. In short, if you believe in the existence of the natural numbers with their usual properties, and you believe that any formula in PA defines in a meaningful way a subset of them, then you will be forced to believe in the consistency of PA.

On the other hand, listening to Voevodsky's lecture, it seems clear that while he is not rejecting the existence of the natural numbers (as perhaps some extreme finitists do), he does not believe that a general formula in PA defines a meaningful subset of the natural numbers. Thus the standard model argument does not convince him, and in fact he seriously entertains the idea that PA may be inconsistent.

On the FOM list there are various assertions that Voevodsky's position is inconsistent, because he has surely proved, and accepted as proved, more elaborate results than the consistency of PA. This is not clear to me, and it seems that a careful analysis of the situation may be somewhat analogous to the analogous analysis of whether large cardinals are required for the proof of FLT --- see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35746/); that is, what might be deduced by a naive analysis of the theories involved, which would suggest that a lot of strong foundational principles are required for $\mathbb A^1$-homotopy and so on, could be misleading upon a more careful investigation. Indeed, it seems quite possible to me that all the arguments that Voevodksy has ever made or signed off on as a referee involve much less comprehension than is required to believe that an arbitrary formula in PA defines a subset of the natural numbers. (The point being that his mathematics will only ever have involved comprehension for rather particular formulas, which are presumably much more concrete than a "general" formula of PA.)

Again, listening to Voevodsky's lecture, it is clear that he makes a careful distinction between mathematical reasoning as carried out by mathematicians, and formal reasoning. Indeed, he seriously entertains the idea that there may not be formally consistent foundations, but at the same time is not rejecting usual mathematics in any sense. Rather, he makes it clear that he believes that the kind of unrestricted nature of constructions required in setting up foundations (e.g. allowing arbitrary formulas in PA to define subsets of the naturals) are likely to always lead to contradictions; but at the same time, he believes that "actual" mathematics will not be affected by this (although a new viewpoint on foundations would be required, a viewpoint that I believe he and his collaborators are actively developing).

So he draws a very strong distinction between "practical" or "natural" mathematical reasoning, and its formalization in a formal system such as PA or ZFC. He seems to believe that Russel-type paradoxes arising from unresricted comprehension will appear in essentially any foundational system, and his rejection of comprehension even over arbitrary formulas of PA seems to me to be a very strong constructivist position (and I hope I'm using this adjective in some approximately correct sense).

So I think the answer to the question should be something like: the consistency of PA can be easily proved using commonly accepted mathematical notions, but not if one limits oneself to sufficiently constructivist notions (as Voevodsky is doing).

---

[The next part of my answer is based on an exchange with an_mo_user on the meta discussion.]

On the FOM mailing list, Friedman posted some correspondence with Voevodsky, in which
Friedman explain that the consistency of PA follows from fifteen (if I remember correctly) generally accepted mathematical principles together with the following statement:

1. every bounded sequence of rationals contains a subsequence such that for this subsequence for all $n$ one has $|q_i - q_j| < 1/n$ for $i,j > n$.

He then asks for Voevodsky's reaction to this: does he continue to maintain that PA is inconsistent, and (hence) reject (1), or does he have some different position?

At this point I am speculating (since Voevodsky hasn't yet answered Friedman's question), but I presume that he will reject statement (1), or rather, will accept as valid only a more limited, sufficiently constructive version of (1). If one takes a formula of PA which determines a non-constructive subset of the naturals (one whose existence Voevodsky rejects), and then takes the corresponding sequence of rationals, one gets a sequence of rationals tending to zero, which I imagine could arise as a candiate sequence $q_n$ in (1). Or alternatively, one could imagine some sequence of rationals such that the subsequence predicted by (1) has indices $i$ which are precisely determined by the condition of belonging to this subset. I would guess that some (probably much more sophisticated) version of these sorts of constructions is taking place in Friedman's proof relating (1) to consistency of PA.

Note that in the question and answer part of the video, Voevodsky makes it pretty clear that he doesn't really believe in the current formalization of the real numbers (calling them an "overidealization") and so it wouldn't surprise me at all if he rejected (1).

Comment: You're right about (1) -- it is a slightly disguised form of the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. Over the base system $RCA_0$ of second-order arithmetic, this statement is equivalent to arithmetic comprehension $ACA_0$ (i.e. all arithmetical formulas define a set of natural numbers).

Another option to completely rejecting (1), is to reject the possibility of iterating (1) arbitrarily often. Indeed, when applied to computable sequences of rationals, (1) only allows the comprehension of sets with Turing degree $\leq 0'$, so one needs to iterate (1) a lot in order to get all arithmetical sets...

Comment: ... However, I have yet to see a sensible formulation of "not being able to iterate" in this and similar contexts. 

Comment: I think Harvey Friedman's claim was somewhat stronger, in that he doesn't assume the base theory `$RCA_0$`.  Instead, he says he relies on some very basic mathematical (meaning not looking like logic or set theory) facts. This is an aspect of what he calls strict reverse mathematics, and it may well be relevant in the present context, since Voevodsky might reject `$RCA_0$`.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a precise form of the stronger assertion (which Friedman was going to present in his upcoming talk, if I got it right).

Comment: @François: "not being to iterate (1) arbitrarily often" could perhaps be taken to mean that one does not accept (1) itself, but only accepts weakened versions of (1) that are provable in RCA_0.  Right?

Comment: @Tim: That is much weaker than what I had in mind. I would like to see a system where the first and second jumps are acceptable, but the $2^{1000}$-st jump is debatable. Obviously, no classical system can do this since you can just iterate the first jump $2^{1000}$ times. However, some ideas along the lines of Yesenin-Volpin's feasibility might allow for something like this.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for the precision.

@Sergey: You may find these drafts by Friedman of interest: http://www.math.osu.edu/~friedman/pdf/StrictRM012305.pdf
http://www.math.osu.edu/~friedman/pdf/InevLogStr082907.pdf
http://www.math.osu.edu/~friedman/pdf/StrictRevMath110709.08.pdf

Comment: François: thanks for the links. Andreas: It's not clear to me if the role of Strict RM in this context would be to reveal essential "facts" being used or rather to hide those ones revealed by ordinary RM behind a heavy ideology. In François' last link, under "Strict RCA$_0$" there is the following disguised form of second-order induction axiom: "every sequence [of integers] has a term of least magnitude" (and also some obscure "extensionality for sequences"). 

Comment: I just had some discussion with Friedman and he confirmed that the set of indices of the subsequence promised by BW could be highly uncomputable. From this perspective, Gentzen's proof is arguably tamer because it requires only that every nonincreasing *primitive recursive* sequence of ordinal notations below $\epsilon_0$ is eventually constant. There is still some "hidden" uncomputability because the point at which the sequence stabilizes is uncomputable, but intuitively it seems more constructive to me.

Answer (score 12):

To be specific, I'll focus on the second question of the title, "Is PA consistent? do we know it?"

As noted by Noah Snyder on the meta thread, this question itself already uses *"philosophical" language like "know"*. So I think it may be viewed it as

$\bullet$ a question in mathematics, if you accept a specific philosophical position such a form of platonism, formalism, constructivism, or ultrafinitism; or

$\bullet$ a question in philosophy of mathematics, if you remain [ignostic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignosticism) regarding the meaning of "know".

So as to stay on-topic, I will only consider the first possibility, and only those four positions that it explicitly lists. In fact, for a **constructivist's** view I absolutely support what Emerton said (only I'm not sure about the border between what Voevodsky actually claimed in his talk vs. what he might have meant), and for a **formalist's** view I agree completely with Todd Trimble's answer. (Indeed, before these two answers appeared I had felt something of those kinds was badly missing from this discussion.) Regarding an **ultrafinitist's** view, I think Mirco Manucci has a point, and I'll incidentally elaborate on another important point made by Qiaochu Yuan on the meta thread.

So I will now pretend that I'm a **platonist** (which is what I usually do when attacking some problem - but certainly not when writing up a proof) and in doing so I'll try to argue that Timothy Chow's first answer is simply wrong. ("Wrong" in platonist's absolute, undefinable sense.)

The problem with Timothy's argument is that it unfairly exploits our subconscious reading of some words in a mathematical text.

When I'm stating a theorem, in a paper or in a talk, I almost never put it like "Theorem (ZFC)." or "Assume ZFC. Then ..." because my area of geometric topology is (or at least is commonly thought to be) very far from foundations, and such pronouncements, commonly seen as tautological, would be very distracting. But I do mean it. (Not that I like ZFC too much, especially so with the uncountable "C" which strikes me as really awful in the context of ZF. But I recognize that socially and in terms of the existing literature to refer to, I don't have much choice - so all my results are, alas, meant to be in ZFC by default.) I also don't start papers and talks by saying that everything will be in ZFC, for the same reason that this information is (as long as my field is concerned) obvious and distracting, and hence is likely to be a repelling factor; and moreover because of my personal negative emotions towards ZFC. I did, in fact, on one occasion stated a "theorem (ZFC)" in a talk, but only to emphasize that I'm not assuming CH or PFA like some previous authors did.

I'm assuming that other authors may have somewhat similar considerations, so in papers, books and talks in my area, I'm reading every "theorem" as a "theorem (ZFC)", or at least as what *could have been meant by the author* to be a theorem in ZFC. There seem to exist people who don't read theorems in this way (I'm thinking, in particular, of applied mathematics and mathematical physics; of Vladimir Arnold; and of experimental mathematics and computer science) but certainly N. Bourbaki and his faithful readers do read them in this way; I also suspect some countries including France and Poland to have more of this tradition than some other ones. The same of course applies to lemmas, problems and conjectures.

Now the situation is different in foundations. You certainly don't read "Problem. Is PA consistent?" as "Problem (ZFC). Is PA consistent?" - at least if you have ever heard of Hilbert's, Goedel's and Gentzen's work on this subject. In set theory, authors usually make it clear what formal system is assumed in their book, chapter or theorem. In other subjects such as proof theory and model theory I understand that the situation is rather complex, but it seems that the prevalent convention in some areas where PA or the second-order arithmetic are more relevant than ZFC is that by default, a "Theorem" could read as "Theorem (no hypotheses whatsoever)." What exactly "no hypotheses whatsoever" means is a separate question, but for the moment I'd like to note that the linguistic/pshychological issue of the clash of conventions for reading *words* like "theorem", "problem" and "proof" is not mentioned in Timothy's first answer, yet is central to its understanding. For this reason I dismiss his argument as pure sophistry.

This doesn't yet address his conclusion - that Con(PA) is true (in the sense of Plato) because we know (in the sense of Plato) a model of PA. (By the way, this purported knowledge usually turns out to be an implicit hypothesis in the "no hypotheses whatsoever" reading.) But how could we possibly *know* that what we usually refer to as "1,2,3,..." (I will abbreviate this as $\Bbb N$) is indeed a model of PA? (Note that "1,2,3,..." is only a name, and not a model itself, due to the presence of the undefined/circularly defined symbol "...".) I see only 3 possibilities:

1) by virtue of a religious belief;

2) we could know it from experience, by having a *physical* model of PA;

3) we could know it from the mind, by demonstrating logically that $\Bbb N$ must be a model of PA.

In connection with the off-topic possibility (1), which I'm not denying, let me only mention some sources: (a) Poincare has devoted quite a few interesting pages to argue 
for his view that the axiom of induction is a [synthetic a priori judgement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%25E2%2580%2593synthetic_distinction), 
(b) Goedel, and in more detail [Roger Penrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadows_of_the_Mind:_A_Search_for_the_Missing_Science_of_Consciousness) used the hypothesis that $\Bbb N$ is a model of PA to argue rather convincingly for certain philosophical propositions related to religion.

The off-topic possibility (2) would have strong consequences for physics, which have not been established yet: given a physical model of PA, apparently either the "physical universe" (the past light cone) is a non-compact [3-manifold](http://www.ams.org/notices/200406/fea-weeks.pdf); or there can be an infinite amount information within its bounded region, which would contradict the [holographic principle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51399/) (which holds in some flavors of string theory) and also some rivals of string theory such as [loop quantum gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity) (which involves a quantized, rather than Euclidean, space-time).

Finally, the possibility (3). Parikh and [Sazonov](http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~sazonov/papers/lcc.ps) have shown (assuming our knowledge of a model of PA) that there exist "truncated" versions of PA which are contradictory due to the truncation, yet the shortest proof of contradiction is too long to fit within the theory; thus the theory doesn't "see" itself as being contradictory. Now imagine a finite computer $X$ on which a Peano-Sazonov arithmetic is implemented. If we happen to have a model of PA, or a bigger computer $Y$ (without tricks) at hand, we could be able to use $Y$ to verify that $X$ does not emulate PA correctly, and so $X$ could be finite. But without $Y$, I don't see how to do it. So it looks like $X$ must seem infinite to its user (unless the user's mind is bigger than $X$).

Could our $\Bbb N$ be just a kind of the computer $X$? That is, could God have faked Sazonov integers for us, and kept Peano integers for himself? I don't see any reason why this couldn't have happened. Please correct me if I'm wrong. (I can't resist recalling that while most people are aware nowadays that the Earth is not flat, the notion of $3$-manifolds other than $\Bbb R^3$ still does not occur to many people outside academia in connection with the physical universe.)

The conclusion is that we don't know that $\Bbb N$ is a model of PA; it is an open problem (in platonist's sense, no hypotheses whatsoever, in particular no assumptions regarding our knowledge of a model of PA). Hence there's also no known reason why Con(PA) couldn't be an open problem (in the same sense).

Comment: *As noted by Noah Snyder on the meta thread, this question itself already uses "philosophical" language like "know".* This is high in criticism, for Many MO questions do this, with the word Why. As a timely simple example, there is "Why do $H_4$ and $M_4$ have the same virtual Euler characteristic?" and I can't dread the poster wants an answer like "because computation X shows it as -1/1440 for each case". I do not count, but I suspect ~25% or more of MO questions are really aimed more philosophical in nature, as the sense of being explanatory of a fact, than just directly what the fact *is*.


Comment: Junkie: I didn't intend this as a criticism, but only to point out that the question can have many correct answers. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Fascinating answer, Sergey.

Comment: "Not that I like ZFC too much, especially so with the uncountable "C" which strikes me as really awful in the context of ZF. But I recognize that socially and in terms of the existing literature to refer to, I don't have much choice...." Pun intended?

Answer (score 11):

I am a little baffled by some of this discussion. It seems everyone agrees that consistency of PA is a theorem, *if* you accept some stronger system, such as ZFC. So, PA is consistent relative to ZFC. Just as obviously, you need *something* to prove consistency of PA; it could be $RCA_0$ plus some presumably innocuous-looking axiom, but obviously $Con(PA)$ doesn't come for free.

Where it gets baffling to me is where the words like "believe", "suspicious", "doubts", etc. enter the discussion; those words properly belong to philosophy. If you take a platonist line, then you may be fairly asked what you "believe", and under those circumstances there is a kind of conventional belief that ZFC is simply *true*. But if you take a formalist line, then there is no commitment to belief; you just take some set of axioms and merrily apply first-order logic$^1$. (But if you are honest about that, then of course you declare what axiom system your theorems are relative to.)

For instance, what Andreas Blass finds "strange, though, is to accept some parts of mathematics (e.g., real analysis) without expressing any doubts, while expressing doubts, based on ontological issues (doubts whether the integers exist), about statements like Con(PA) that seem to require far less ontological commitment than real analysis." It's not clear to me what 'ontological commitment' a skeptic of $Con(PA)$ would have to particular statements of analysis$^2$, but a formalist will have none, and as Emerton points out (in his speculations on Voevodsky's likely reaction to one of Friedman's questions), there are plenty of seemingly innocent-looking analytic statements subject to constructivist 'doubt', if 'doubt' is indeed the right word to use here. (A formalist might prefer to say instead, 'constructively invalid'.) I can't see why any of this would be controversial.

1. First-order logic is a kind of bottom line for most formalists. There are some divergences as to whether one uses the principle of the excluded middle, or whether one treats equality as intensional or extensional -- much of Voevodsky's fascinating recent work is in intensional type theory and what might be termed its "homotopical semantics".
2. If someone is observed not to express doubts about certain analytic statements but express doubts about $Con(PA)$ -- as has no doubt happened in the history of mathematics -- it doesn't necessarily mean that person is confused. It could simply mean that the person has decided to "go along with" ZFC in one discussion -- maybe he is "suspending disbelief" just for the sake of an interesting discussion -- but in another discussion with manifestly metamathematical overtones, he has decided to "reactivate disbelief". Or, maybe he is just being mum about his having or not having beliefs.

Comment: ...       Word.

Comment: You're welcome; just call me Todd, please. :-) 

Comment: ok. I needed 5 more characters to post it.

Comment: Dear Todd, I think that one reason for your confusion is that while (I want to guess) you are a formalist, many others are platonists.  In particular, I think it is at least *a priori* possible to imagine that mathematics takes place prior to foundations of mathematics (this is at least historically true), and then it is harder to phrase results as being of a relative nature in a formalist nature; they instead are relative to certain basic beliefs.  E.g. I believe that the real number as a complete ordered field exists, and then I deduce xyz about them; I believe that the natural numbers ...

Comment: exist, with all their subsets, and so obtain a model of PA.  (But not a model in ZFC; a model in some less formal sense, a mental model if you like.)   Perhaps what I want to say is that Platonist beliefs can occur prior to foundational beliefs, so that one can admit certain beliefs without (necessarily) believing in ZFC.  In fact, I think that
this is close to how many practicing mathematicians work (they may say they believe in ZFC, but I'm not sure that that isn't just a social convention) --- I should say that I don't have anything but anecdotal evidence for this, though, so don't take ...

Comment: ... it too seriously as an assertion.  So let me close by saying that since I started reading online math forums, and so getting a broader cross-section of mathematical points-of-view than I get in person, I have been surprised at how many formalists there seem to be!  (So, while you seem to find the formalist position more natural, and the platonist position perhaps less so, my situation is somewhat the reverse.)   Anyway, none of this is meant as any criticism at all of your answer, which I think is very lucid; just as some commentary that might shed light on the aspects of the ...

Comment: ... discussion that seem odd to you.  Best wishes, Matthew

Comment: Dear Matthew: I don't think I'm actually confused here :-) Take it as mock bafflement, if you will. My real concern is to point out the elements of the discussion which seem philosophical, and not to take a hard line one way or the other (even if, as you rightly surmise, I have strongly formalist leanings (-: ) Best wishes to you. 

Comment: Dear Todd, I didn't really imagine that you were confused, either! I find this discussion interesting partly because I am not a formalist, but am probably closer to a Platonist who imagines that in fact everything significant that he proves could be made constructive if necessary.  (In short, I think --- or at least hope --- that my mathematics is independent, more or less, of the background foundations.)  Hence my (perhaps overly strong) reaction to your intimation that Platonist's more-or-less automatically embrace ZFC.  Best wishes, Matthew.  (And sorry for leaving so many comments!) 

Comment: Todd, what can still remain controversial, even if one is a formalist, is a statement such as, "The consistency of PA is an open problem."  Some formalists regard this statement as plainly true and that it can only be settled (in the negative) by exhibiting an inconsistency.  Others would say that the term "open question" is only properly applied to statements of the form "Con(PA) is a theorem of formal system X," and that it's not really open because we know the answer for pretty much any of the standard choices for X.

Comment: Dear Matthew -- not at all! I enjoy reading your comments. Just one thing: I really didn't mean to imply that Platonists automatically embrace ZFC, but rather that ZFC has become a widely shared conventional background for mathematical discourse, and that the Platonist who adopts ZFC does so believing it simply to be true. 

Comment: Timothy, while I may profess agnosticism about all such matters, I *confess* that I actually believe Con(PA). :-) I'd not heard the controversy you refer to; do you know some place in the literature where this is discussed? I admit that I'm not too sympathetic to the second of those two positions: it would carry little weight in the disastrous event that a formal deduction in PA of 0 = 1 were actually produced! 

Comment: I can't cite any literature off the top of my head that deals with that particular controversy specifically.  Some of the literature on logicism touches on it.  But as for what would happen if we were to find a formal deduction in PA of 0=1, all that would mean is that "Con(PA) is a theorem of formal system X" would now be known to be true for a few more values of X, such as X = PA.

Comment: That's an amusing way of putting it! But then couldn't you turn that around and say [to those in the second camp], "Con(PA) is (encodable as) a theorem of PA" is currently an open problem? :-) 

Comment: Todd, I can't quite tell how serious you're being, but my main point is that a formalist can decide to treat statements of the form "X is an open problem" as meaning "Neither X nor ~X is known to be provable in ZFC."  Then the formalist's verbal behavior with regard to the term "open problem" will be virtually indistinguishable from that of anyone else's.  I think this causes less confusion than the practice followed by some formalists, of doing what I say above for *most* statements X but making an exception for (e.g.) X = "PA is inconsistent," which they take to be directly meaningful.

Comment: Timothy: (1) I was being serious, and (2) I believe you've made this point several times by now. I'm not sure which formalists you're imputing this behavior to, but I understand the point you're making. At the same time, surely for *any* theory T, "T is inconsistent" has the direct meaning that there is a deduction of the sequent $\top \vdash \bot$ in T. 

Answer (score 4):

Here are four quotes:

Quote 1. [Vladimir Voevodsky](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-May/015506.html)

"To put it very shortly I think that inconsistency of Peano arithmetic as well as inconsistency of ZFC are open and very interesting problems in mathematics. Consistency on the other hand is not an interesting problem since it has been shown by Gödel to be impossible to prove."

Quote 2. [Vladimir Voevodsky](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-May/015506.html)

"In fact, one would obviously expect that it will be easier to prove the inconsistency of principles which can be used to prove consistency of PA than inconsistency of PA itself."

Quote 3. [Todd Trimble](https://mathoverflow.net/a/66764/461)

"It seems everyone agrees that consistency of PA is a theorem, *if* you accept some stronger system, such as ZFC. So, PA is consistent relative to ZFC. Just as obviously, you need *something* to prove consistency of PA; it could be $RCA_0$ plus some presumably innocuous-looking axiom, but obviously $Con(PA)$ doesn't come for free."

Quote 4. [Tim Chow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/66789/461)

"Finally, to answer the new question that Franklin has asked, about whether the consistency of any of the systems in which Con(PA) has been proved has been proved: The answer is, "not in any sense that you would likely find satisfying." For example, one can "prove" that PRA + induction up to $\epsilon_0$ is consistent, in the sense that the consistency proof can be formalized in ZF, which as I said above is the usual standard for settling mathematical questions. If, however, the reason that you're asking the question is that you *doubt* the consistency of PA, and are hoping that you can settle those doubts by proving the consistency of PA in some "weaker" system that can then be proved consistent using "weaker" assumptions that you don't have any doubts about, then you're basically out of luck. This, roughly speaking, was Hilbert's program for eliminating doubts about the consistency of infinitary set theory. The hope was that one could prove the consistency of (say) ZF on the basis of a weak system such as (say) PRA, about which we had no doubts. But Gödel showed that not only is this impossible, but even if we allow all of ZF into our arsenal, we *still* can't prove the consistency of ZF. For better or for worse, this tempting road out of skepticism about consistency is intrinsically blocked."

Here are two questions:

Question 1: Is there a proof of Con(PA) in ZFC?

Question 2: Is Peano arithmetic consistent?

I think everybody (including Voevodsky) agrees that the answer to Question 1 is Yes, and in particular that Question 1 is *not* open.

Is Question 2 open?

As explained in Quotes 1 and 2, Voevodsky thinks that Question 2 *is* open.

Quotes 3 and 4 suggest (in my opinion) that Todd Trimble and Tim Chow agree with the premise of Voevodsky's argument.

Voevodsky's argument looks very compelling to me.

Also I think it is unlikely that Voevodsky made a mistake in such a simple reasoning; that, if he had made such a mistake, somebody would have pointed it out to him; and that, if somebody had pointed out such a mistake to him, he would have been clever enough to understand it, and honest enough to acknowledge it.

Comment: 'Explicit proof of Con(PA) in ZFC'? Do you mean one where all the details in ZFC-language are written out? Or in a proof assistant?

Comment: @DavidRoberts - Sorry, I didn't express myself well. I shouldn't have said "explicit". I edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Dear Tim, I read your same argument (up to homotopy) on FOM a couple of days ago and I must say: NOT convincing. You may ask why, and I am glad to tell you: the $n$ in the induction formula and the x and y in the  ∃y:y+y=x are not integers, but TERMS in the language of PA. I certainly have no problems manipulating terms using PA, but about integers I know nothing, in fact I doubt they actually exist (and by the way, I am not alone: Nelson, for one, doubts them too). And I do not mean I doubt that 2^10^10^100000000 exists -in fact it does, just another fancy term), I mean I doubt that even the **NUMBER 5** exists. In fact, let me tell u more: what is **5**? Answer: the (infinite) equivalence class of terms in the language of PA which are provably equal to SSSSS0. Do you REALLY know this class? I doubt. Perhaps some incredibly complicated term will eventually be proved equal to SSSSS0, and nobody now knows it, or even fancies about it. Bottom line,  your argument is basically this: IF there is such a thing as the integers and I know them, THEN PA is (obviously) consistent. A small IF for you, a gigantic one for me.

Coda: do I believe that PA is inconsistent? I would not bet my house on that. But I would not bet my life on PA being consistent either...

Comment: Dear Mirco, I don't see the difference between faith in numbers and faith in symbols. The one unique (symbolic) entity that we always refer to when we write down something like "SSSSS0" does not strike me as any less mysterious than the equivalence class of all 5-element sets. If you give numbers to the devil, he's going to take the free semigroup generated by the letters used in mathematical discourse.

Comment: I agree with SJR.  If you don't believe in numbers, then I don't see why you believe in PA.  You ask me, what is 5?  I reply, what is a symbol?

Comment: Who said that I believe in PA? who has mentioned the word "belief", ? Not I. What I do believe is that PA is a beautiful mathematical game to play with (I love the game of GO, but I do not think it reveals the mysterious nature of the universe, or perhaps I do, after a couple of glasses of wine), in fact in my modest opinion the best there is in math, and moreover it does formalize well something that is of paramount practical  important in our world, namely COUNTING. 

Comment: As for SSSSS0, I used the word TERM, not symbol, and deliberately so. A symbol conjures up something arcane, as if it "symbolized" something else. But a term is something my laptop can understand, I can write a simple program that tells him when something is a well formed term of PA or it is not. Of course in real life SSSSS0 means something, it says"start at 0, then $0, then.... , ok now stop ". But this is a topic for cognitive sciences, not mathematical theology

Comment: To work with PA, one has to be able to tell the difference between SSSS0 and SSSSS0.  How are you able to tell the difference?  I personally do so by counting the number of symbols and noting that one has 5 symbols and the other doesn't.  Since you don't know what 5 is, this technique is unavailable to you.  And if you can't keep track of the difference between SSSS0 and SSSSS0 then you certainly can't determine whether an alleged PA-proof is correct, or whether your computer program is debugged.  So I don't even know what you mean when you say that "PA might be inconsistent."

Comment: Tim, I said that I do not know what the number 5 is (ie the equivalent class of all closed terms which PA proves to be equal to SSSSS0) -and I am pretty sure you do not know it either-, I did not say I do not know how to COUNT :)))). SSSSSS0 is the SUCCESSOR of SSSS0, and thus it is greater than SSSS0 (as a term, of course). As for the other issue, well, let us say that if a standard theorem prover implemented in your favorite language comes up with a verifiable proof that 0 = S0 using only the axioms of PA and baby logic, I will conclude that PA is inconsistent. 

Comment: anyway, let us leave it at that. Admins decided to close this question, and I think the decision was a wise one, as this is not the forum for speculating on FOM.  I apologize for questioning the dogma of the existence of the NN here, but I am pretty sure most people will sleep well regardless of my doubts. 

Comment: @Mirco: I don't see how you can count to 5 if you don't know what 5 is, nor do I see how you can tell the difference between SSSS0 and SSSSS0 unless you know what terms are, and the concept of a term doesn't seem any clearer to me than the concept of a number.  It seems to me that you're just pretending not to know what 5 is in order to win an argument.  Even Nelson wouldn't argue that he doesn't know what 5 is.

Comment: As for your argument, it is you that seem not to accept the obvious, for instance Andreas Blass above understood immediately my position (read again his answer), though he probably will not agree. But at any rate, I try to explain it to you: certainly I know $$$$$0, here it is: I write down 0, then S0, then SS0,.. then SSSSS0, and then SSSSS0. BINGO! Now, as I mentioned above, my laptop can be programmed to do just the same, and even to check whether a sequence is well formed or not. For instance, it would reject SS0SSSS0 as invalid. Now, does my laptop know the natural numbers? I doubt it.

Comment: On Nelson: In his Confessions of an apostate mathematician, a freely available paper which I strongly recommend that u read, he describes his "satori" when he finally lost his faith in numbers. To him, as to me, only syntax exists (at least as far as formal math goes), and that is it. I dunno if, in case you asked him whether he believes that 5 (I mean the number) exists, he would tell you yes or no (send him a n email). But, if he is coherent with his tenets, he should tell you no 

Comment: @SJR Yes, if I give the numbers to the devil, he is gonna take the free semigroup T= { 0 , $0, ....SSSSSSS0, .......} (and many other gadgets too). Well, let him take it! I can teach you how to play GO (if you do not know it already ) in 1/2 hour, and then you will be able to play. Do you need to know all the configurations of GO to play correctly? Answer: NO. Likewise, you can learn the rules of Q (baby arithmetic) and start playing (ie counting). And if you give me a candidate term, I can certainly determine whether it is a valid one or not, without T.

Comment: 5 is the number of fingers on my right hand. Now for everybody's sake I should be really careful not to get into a nasty accident involving my fingers, because that would make PA inconsistent.

Comment: Andrej, worry not, that would not make PA inconsistent, but it would force you to invent some other device to count up to 5 (perhaps you can use your feet). 

PS many folks seem to have the idea that I gotta know N before I know how to count, whereas I believe just the opposite: it is because we know how to count first that we have concocted this creature from fairyland called N. 

Comment: @Mirco: As far as I can see, Andreas Blass did not respond to your remark, but only to Sergey's. I am familiar with Nelson's paper and again, the doubts he expresses are about N, not about 5. What I am saying is that if you know how to count to 5, then you know what 5 is. You might not define 5 in the way someone else does (in terms of equivalence classes and whatnot), but you do know what 5 is, even if you don't know what N is.

Comment: @Tim: if you mean that I know the term $$$$$$0, of course I do know it, and I also know a few other equivalent terms (if you wish, you could say that I believe in 5 as a PROVISIONAL  equivalence class of terms i have constructed, but such a class is a work in fieri. It seems to me that you either do not understand what I am saying, or you just play as if you did not understand me. So I will tell you clearly: I DO NOT BELIEVE IN NUMBERS. I do believe that there is a wonderful SYNTACTIC game, the Peano Game, which also serves us well to count. Here is my slogan: semantics is just other syntax. 

Comment: As for Nelson (I quote him verbatim):

I must relate how I lost my faith in Pythagorean numbers. One
morning at the 1976 Summer Meeting of the American Mathematical
Society in Toronto, I woke early. As I lay meditating about numbers,
I felt the momentary overwhelming presence of one who convicted me
of arrogance for my belief in the real existence of an infinite world of
numbers, leaving me like an infant in a crib reduced to counting on my
fingers. Now I live in a world in which there are no numbers save those
that human beings on occasion construct. 

Comment: Finally Andreas Blass: I did not say he agrees with what I say, only he understands my point of view (unlike u). Here is the quotation:
--As Mirco Mannucci's answer suggests, the alternatives labeled 1) and 2) in the question are (for some people) not mutually exclusive. The consistency of PA indeed "has a proof as valid as any other theorem in math" (as Timothy Chow's answer pretty much shows) --- alternative 1. Nevertheless, if one doesn't believe the integers exist, then the bottom drops out from that and also from almost everything else in math. -- 
Crystal clear, isn't it? 


Comment: @Mirco: I understand Nelson's position, but I agree with you that I don't understand yours. Your quote from Nelson confirms what I said, which is that he doesn't believe in N, but he does believe in 5, since 5 is a number that we "on occasion construct." Other than this point, I do not wish to debate your position, even though I do not agree with it.

Comment: @Tim I propose a draw :). If you do agree that the "numbers" can be those (partial/incomplete) equivalence classes of terms of arithmetics which one has actually computed, then yes, I believe in 5. You are obviously a very smart fellow, so you can certainly understand me if I say this: to me N is a work-in-progress, not in the usual (intuitionist) sense that is an initial segment of what others call N, but in the strongest sense that my N is a PARTIAL TERM MODEL of PA. Imagine how you construct the term model in standard logic, and now imagine that it is not finished. That thing is N for me. 

Comment: Now, allow me to go a bit further: take the category of partial term models of PA, let us call it PA-PTM, with maps given by $TM_1\rightarrow TM_2$ iff $TM_2$ extends $TM_1$ as a partial term model. This category is my arithmetical universe, perhaps one could call it a Volpin-Nelson universe. If one believes in countable colimits, I can even tell you what your platonic $N$ is: the terminal object of this cat. 

Answer (score 2):

The following is a (I hope correct) adaption of an argument of H. Friedman made on the FOM list, which I found very instructive.

The following statements are esentially equivalent:

a. The consistency of PA is *proved*.

b. It is *proved* that for every bounded sequence of rational numbers there exists a subsequence $q_i$ such that for every $n$ one has 
$$ |q_i - q_j| < 1/n $$ 
for $i,j \ge n$.

So, I understand that one can have doubts about b. too, but still I think it clearly demonstrates that if one doubts that the consistency of PA is proved, then one has to doubt  all kinds of other classical mathemtical facts.

Comment: Dear unknown, I agree with this answer, and my impression, from listening to Voevodsky's lecture, is that he *does* reject a lot of classical mathematical facts, in so far as he adopts an extremely constructivist stance.  (See my answer for a slight elaboration on this).  Best wishes,  Matthew

Comment: The Friedman correspondence is in http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-May/015506.html


Comment: This is not quite what Friedman said. Firstly, I find your "proved" misleading (proved in what formal system?). Secondly, your b involves quantification over sets of integers, so I don't think that your assertion that a implies b corresponds to any actual theorem. What Friedman said is that RCA_0 + (your b without "proved") is equivalent to a system that interprets PA. Thirdly, and I think most importantly, the system RCA_0 allows induction over formulas involving universal quantification over sets of integers (which PA doesn't).

Comment: (cont'd) And this is what I don't buy in Friedman's argument. I don't find the notion of "a set of integers" sufficiently unambiguous to be quantified over. Even in ZFC, what is and what is not a set of integers is a matter depending on additional axioms (e.g. this can be affected by forcing). I do hope that our understanding of what are sets of integers will be clarified by seeing them as types (non-discrete in general) - of course if the univalent foundations program succeeds in explaining how to do it.

Comment: @Sergey Melikhov: Thank you for your remark. First, my '(I hope correct)' was meant to indicate that I claim 'non-expert-status', perhaps I should have been more explict regarding this; I appolgize in case I should have misrepresented what Friedman wrote. Second, my answer in particular the 'proved' is (of course) meant in the spirit of the question, in particular 'edit, point 1', so rather in a vague sense; this non-technical nature of my answer is further illustrated by my (unqualified) usage of 'essentially'. Third, I reproduce what Friedman wrote that I tried to adapt (to fit the format):

Comment: from an email of Friedman to Voevodsky (to be found behind the link provided by Junkie--thank you, Junkie, for this--towards the very end  ): 'It appears that contemplating the inconsistency of PA forces  
contemplating a refutation of
"every bounded infinite sequence of rationals contains a 1/n Cauchy  
subsequence"...' [verbatim except for replacing an asterisk by quotation marks to avoid formatting here]. This is what I tried to reproduce filling in the definition of 1/n C.S., taking it to mean (and this interpretation seems clearly suggested by the context there): 

Comment: if one takes a position that allows to say con(PA) is not proved, then  one took a position that implies that "every bou. inf. sequ. of rat. contains a 1/n Cauchy subsequence" is neither a proved mathematical fact [with the same meaning of proved]. Perhaps I adapted this badly (or misunderstood it altogether, did I?), but I hope that this explantions makes my intention transparent. 
Finally, I have no particular personal stance in this disc., but simply browsed the disc. on FOM and found this argument of Friedman fitting for the disc. at hand and interesting, so I tried to 'reproduce' it. 
  

Comment: Added: I did not see the second comment of Sergey Melikhov before finalizing my comments. However, it seems this does not have to severe consequences, except that I should add (again) that I am not qualified  to 'defend' Friedman's argument. As said I tried to 'quote' him. 
In case, I should misrepresent his views I will of course modify my answer. If this is not so, please consider my answer as more-or-less a (free) quotation that I found instructive.   

Comment: @Sergey: If you're suspicious of the use of sets in $RCA_0$, you should note that any $\Pi_2^0$ theorems of $RCA_0$ are provable in $PRA$ (primitive recursive arithmetic).  I don't know the details of Friedman's proof well enough to be sure, but because of this conservation result, I suspect that it will be possible to deduce the consistency of $PA$ from the Bolzano-Weierstrass assertion using only $PRA$-reasoning.

Comment: Timothy: I would be interested to see this deduction when it appears.

Comment: @Sergey: After I made my previous comment, I realized that it doesn't quite make sense, since the Bolzano-Weierstrass assertion can't literally be stated in PRA. This does make me wonder, though: Do you think that the statement is even meaningful? It starts off, "For every sequence of rational numbers..." An arbitrary sequence of rational numbers is awfully close to an arbitrary set of rational numbers. Given your skepticism about sets of integers, are you concerned that any statement that starts off "For every sequence of rational numbers" doesn't even have a precise mathematical meaning?

Comment: Timothy, you're right, I see a problem with its meaning. It has a clear meaning in the sense of Formalism, provided you specify a base theory. It might get a precise intuitive meaning if we learn to understand all sets as types some day, but we're not there yet. Also it does have a *sufficiently* precise meaning for many purposes, e.g. as long as we're concerned with the kind of problems studied in analysis (without mentioning Cohen reals or anything like that). The latter claim might even have some supporting theorem in Reverse Mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

I'd been very interested in foundational questions for a long time so I think I can say something about it. To understand the question I think it is necessary make some comment: mathematical logic is the study of mathematical theories via mathematics itself. To make theorem about theories first you have to define what is a formula, a theory and a proof, so first you need a (meta-)theory in which you make your demonstration about your theory: usually this (meta-)theory is Zermelo Fraenkel set theory without infinite axiom. This means that every proof of a theorem about a theory is valid if  the meta-theory is consistent, if that's not the case then we cannot say anything because in a inconsistent theory you can deduce everything (that if you use classical logic).
This says that we cannot prove the consistency of a theory in an absolute sense but we can only reduce consistency of a theory to the consistency of another theory: so I think today is pointless wonder if PA is consistent, unless you don't believe in the existence of natural number which satisfy all of the Peano Axioms, such existence is the proof of consistence of PA, because it's well know (or I hope so) that a theory with a model is consistent. (In particular if you accept the consistence of ZFC the you can prove PA consistency in this theory). Just one more thing: if you don accept the existence of natural numbers which satisfy PA (and so of a universe which is a model of ZFC) then you cannot accept lots of mathematics that is derived from it. I hope this answer your question.

Comment: Dear ineff, Regarding "you cannot accept lots of mathematics that
[is] derived[d] from it"; it may be that you instead accept some constructivist versions of standard mathematical theorems.  I think there are many (or at least some) working mathematicians who go along with ZFC (so to speak) but have something of a constructivist view, in that they believe that their theorems are of a sufficiently constructive nature that it doesn't really matter what the background foundational theory is.  Regards, Matthew

Comment: Note that PRA is sufficient for most meta-theoretic purposes. (You can do pretty much everything except model theory.) Also, PRA is considerably weaker than PA.

Comment: @Emerton: thanks for the correction, I edited;
@Emerton and F.G. Dorais: I didn't mean that ZFC is the only system we can use, anyway it's well know that a lot of mathematics cannot be derived without those systems or without something with the same deductive power. By the way the point of my discussion was that:
1. a proof of consistence is just a reduction of the consistence of a theory to the consistence of the meta-theory (so in the end we have to accept some theory without any proof of is consistence);
2. if we accept the existence of a model for PA we also have to accept its consistence.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your question B

> B) Is it a mathematical question?

Normally when we consider it, yes. But we can also consider it as an *empirical* question.

How so? Well, there are two kinds of models of $PA$:

- Those for which $Con(PA)$ (this includes the standard model)
- Those for which $\lnot Con(PA)$

The issue is that models in both groups are logically coherent, and in fact very similar to one another, empirically (in that true finite statements in both are the same). So ultimately, the question "$Con(PA)?$" can be rephrased empirically "Do we live in a $Con(PA)$ or $\lnot Con(PA)$ universe?". If we find a natural number $n$ that encodes a valid proof of $PA \vdash 0=1$, we know we are in the latter.