# Iterated Gentzen: or, a Sith objection to the proof of consistency of PA

Tags: lo.logic, foundations, peano-arithmetic, ordinal-analysis

$\DeclareMathOperator\PRA{PRA}\DeclareMathOperator\WF{WF}\DeclareMathOperator\Con{Con}\DeclareMathOperator\PA{PA}$Preamble: In the year … in  a galaxy far far away, a nasty Sith named Darth Dubious (DD)  asks a Jedi,  Obi Wan Mathobi  (OWM),  about the consistency of PA:

DD: How do you know that PA is consistent?

OWM: Don't you know that many centuries ago a great Mathematician  from Terra by the name of Gentzen proved its consistency?

DD: Of course I do. He proved that $\PRA + \WF(\epsilon_0) \vdash \Con(\PA)$, but ….

OWM: But what? Are you going to tell me the usual story that the proof is not finitistic enough?

DD: I dare not, Master Mathobi. I happily concede that the proof is valid. Yet, I have still a doubt lingering in my brain:  how do you know that
$G(0) =\PRA + \WF(\epsilon_0)$ *itself* is not contradictory?

As I said, the proof seems quite acceptable to me, but not any argument that $G(0)$ is consistent because it has a model in some very infinitistic theory such as ZF.

Rather, let us say that we apply Gentzen's argument to $G(0)$, and that we can prove the following:
$\PRA + \WF(\alpha_0) \vdash \Con( G(0))$.

Now, I would surmise that $\alpha_0 > \epsilon_0$, right?

OWM: It would seem so. I suspect (but I am not sure) that else $\PA$ would be able to prove the consistency of $G(0)$. Need to ask some other Jedis more skillful in Ordinal Analysis ….

DD: Ok, waiting for them I tell you where I am going, although methinks you know it already: I am going to
repeat my argument again, and create a chain of theories $G(i)$ such that each one Gentzen-proves the consistency of the previous one by an ever greater countable ordinal. If necessary, we can iterate beyond $\omega$. Now, is this series of countable recursive ordinals cofinal in the set of all countable recursive ordinals? If yes, I am afraid you ask for too much, because then I would have to accept induction all the way to $\omega^{CK}_1$.

If, on the other hand, it does not, I would like to know which is the upper bound.

THAT ordinal is the actual price to pay to secure $\PA$'s consistency.

> Question: What is wrong with DD's argument? Or, if it is sound, any clues on the upper bound ordinal which would secure the consistency of the entire chain of iterated Gentzen theories

ADDENDUM I started with $\PA$ but, mutatis mutandis, you can begin from $\operatorname Q$, in which case instead of $\epsilon_0$ you use  $\omega$.

Comment: There's a step "Now, I would surmise that $\alpha_0 > \epsilon_0$, right?" which is not fully justified, and seems to be the obvious place to look for trouble.

Comment: LSpice, thanks for your editing. My eye sight is not that good, and I am quite sloppy. As for your point, of course, that is the "critical point", but we need details, don't we? Some Jedi Masters here know how to dig it, I trust....

Comment: PS Even if the ordinal inequality is wrong at stage 0, to secure Gentzen we would need an argument that it is UNIFORMLY so, ie that it never goes up.

Comment: If the argument already fails at step 0 then it has nowhere further to go, as $\operatorname{Con}(\epsilon_0) \vdash \operatorname{Con}(\alpha_0)$ in this case (right?).  Anyway I am no logician, and agree that experts will chime in.  I was just pointing out that there was an obvious point on which to focus.

Comment: I do not think so. Probably, but not surely. It needs an argument that for each alpha (index of G_alpha), the ordinal does not get pushed up. And, of course, this argument must also be finitistic...

Comment: In order to really formalize this question, you may have to be more careful in terms of formalizing what you mean by $\mathrm{WF}(\alpha)$. $\mathrm{PRA}$ is a first-order theory of arithmetic, so right off the bat full well-foundedness is not formalizable. You can only talk about well-foundedness relative to descending sequences definable with formulas of some given complexity (and, indeed, Gentzen only needs it for some relatively low complexity).

Comment: The other issue is that really you have to talk about specific ordinal notations (as in specific computable copies of the ordinals). Over a sufficiently strong base theory these different forms of the assumption should be provably equivalent, but I don't know if this true for arbitrarily large computable ordinals, and I don't know if it's true for $\mathrm{PRA}$.

Comment: @JamesHanson what you say is correct, and helped me correct a silly statement I made inside: if the sequence of ordinals were cofinal in the RECURSIVE ordinals, it would have as upper bound the Kleene ordinal. So, thank you. Having said that, though, I do not see your point: of course we are talking about ordinals and well-foundedness inside an arithmetical theory, and of course if you choose as a starting point a weak theory you must pay attention to how you encode the recursive relation, the ordinal notation, and whatelse. But the bottom line remains: it can be done, so that

Comment: G(0) is a perfectly legitimate arithmetical theory, seemingly incomparable in strength with  PA, and proving its consistency. So, Darth Dubious's argument applies: what is the ordinal strength needed to prove CON(G(0))? and also, you can define the same issue for a recursive list of ordinal numbers. Now, aside the little SF story, what is at stake is: perhaps the ordinal strength necessary to prove CON(G(0))  is not greater  than epsilon_0, and the same applies to all successive iterations. In that case Master Mathobi wins: you only have to believe induction up to e_0 and bingo! you can

Comment: sleep well at night. But I am a bit skeptical about that. Anyway thanks for your contribution anyway

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here: specifically, the question "[What] ordinal is the actual price to pay to secure PA's consistency[?]" is confusing to me because I don't know what "secure PA's consistency" means. I don't understand why $\epsilon_0$ isn't enough - the fact that we can further question the consistency of $PRA+WF(\epsilon_0)$  (ignoring precise phrasing issues) doesn't seem relevant to me, since we don't need the additional hypothesis of that theory's consistency to conclude $Con(PA)$ within that theory. So what exactly do you mean by "secure the consistency of?"

Comment: Ok @NoahSchweber: suppose for one second that G(0) were inconsistent. If G(0) were inconsistent, it would prove ANYTHING, ex falso sequitur quodlibet, right? So, what Gentzen proves in fact is: IF G(0) is consistent, THEN PA is consistent too. Now, how do I know that G(0) is consitent? Of course, I can resort to, say, ZF, but then why bother with G(0) in the first place? So, I say, very well, let us apply the same therapy to  G(0). Assume that to use the same type of argument, I need another ordinal, say alpha_1. Now I repeat the chain. I have a sequence of recursive ordinals,

Comment: @MircoA.Mannucci So what exactly are you looking for? To me, "secure the foundation of PA" means exactly "when granted as an assumption, it implies $Con(PA)$." So the issue you raise just isn't a problem for how I understand the question: if we grant that $PRA+WF(\epsilon_0)$ is *true*, then surely it's *consistent*.

Comment: e_0 =alpha_0, alpha_1, ...... etc. Now I wanna know what is the sup of this sequence. If I know it, I know how much of ordinal induction  is necessary to swallow, to ensure that PA is consitent, WITHOUT resorting to ZF or anything else for that matter. Makes sense now?

Comment: No, because I don't understand what *is* satisfactory, only one thing you find *un*satisfactory. For example, what does "etc" mean - does that sequence go on for $\omega$-many steps, or what?

Comment: By the way, I hope you are one of the downgraders of this question. You know why? If you are, I like you. And I like you because you had the good taste of saying this question does not make sense to me, rather than saying nothing at all. Perhaps my question does not make sense, though alllow me to say that so far it does, but I need criticisms, objections, etc.

Comment: (Yes, I did downvote - I don't downvote without saying why unless it's a question by a user I already know becomes very aggressive in comments. Those are, granted, extremely rare.)

Comment: Good point. Let us start with that, let us continue omega steps. But even better, because perhaps I have more than omega times to say I do not trust the last step, let us continue till allowed, namely as long as I can go staying within recursive ordinals. Now, many things can happen: perhaps the series is stationary at epsilon_0, in which case I would be very happy, or perhaps is monotonic increasing, or perhaps oscillates. I hope someone will tell me which one

Comment: BRAVO Noah. Actually, twice bravo, one for verbalizing your objections, and the other one to say clearly so. I have no ego here, it may well that my question was not as transparent as I hope it to be, or whatever. Thanks !

Comment: PS You  said the magic word: TRUE. I know exactly what you mean, but to me it means nothing. There is nothing true anywhere in math, as far as I can see . There are PROOFS, and if by true you mean in N, then I tell you again: why bother? PA is true in N just as well. But point is, that is not what Gentzen had in mind.Gentzen wanted to show CON(PA) with what he understood to be finitistic arguments, and there ain't anything finitistic about N...

Comment: I once asked somewhere how to find the ordinal strength of PA+CON(PA) and it turned out to be $\epsilon_0$, the same as that of PA itself.  I don't remember the explanation of this.  The main conclusion that ordinal strength wasn't as linear as it might sound.  Maybe your $\alpha_0$ also turns out to be the same as $\epsilon_0$.

Comment: Yes, it can be so, that is what Mathobi hopes, and perhaps it is indeed the case. But remember, that takes care of G(0), would be great that all G(i) had ordinal strength $\epsilon_0$. We shall see....

Comment: I was going to write this as an answer to the question supporting Obi Wan Mathobi's hope, but it's too incomplete to post as one. In "The Realm of Ordinal Analysis" (proposition 2.24, preprint) M. Rathjen writes that if we have a subsystem of $Z_2$ that includes all axioms of $PA$ (e.g. $PA$ itself), adding a semantically true $\Sigma_1^1$ statement doesn't change its proof-theoretic ordinal. So $\varepsilon_0=\vert PA\vert=\vert PA+Con(PA)\vert=\vert PA+Con(PA+Con(PA))\vert=\ldots$, including all finite iterations.

Comment: But Rathjen's proposition uses a formulation of proof-theoretic ordinal called $\vert\cdot\vert_{sup}$, which is different from the formulation $PRA+WF(\alpha_i)\vdash Con(G(i))$ in the question. Also I'm not sure if the proof of Rathjen's proposition is finitistic enough for Obi Wan Mathobi.

Answer (score 4):

Mathobi is making a different argument in the comments on this post than in the question itself: in the post Mathobi is considering how far we need to justify transfinite induction to prove $G(i)$ consistent over PRA, while in the comments you mentioned Mathobi's hope would be supported if PA+Con(PA) had proof-theoretic ordinal $\varepsilon_0$. In favor of the position in the comments, the theories PA, PA+Con(PA), PA+Con(PA+Con(PA))), etc. (for finite iterations) all have the same strength, $\varepsilon_0$. However, we can show $G(1)$ is quite a bit stronger than PA+Con(PA), and each $G(i+1)$ is stronger than $G(i)$.

But first, we need to distinguish a few concepts: there's more than one formulation of proof-theoretic ordinal, the most commonly used one is $\vert\, .\,\vert_{sup}$, and $\vert\, .\,\vert_{Con}$ is the rendering of Gentzen's result in your question, $\textrm{PRA+TI}(\alpha)\vdash\textrm{Con(T)}$. (These are described in more detail in Rathjen's "[The Realm of Ordinal Analysis](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/realm.pdf)".) However $\vert\, .\,\vert_{Con}$ is only useful with respect to a "natural" ordinal representation system fixed in advance, so for the rest of this answer we fix a representation system such as one based on [Veblen's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function). Let's also define theories $H(0)=\textrm{PA}$, and $H(i+1)=\textrm{PA+Con}(H(i))$.

Here we get our first result comparing proof-theoretic ordinals of these theories, which is that for all $i<\omega$ we have $\vert H(i)\vert_{sup}=\varepsilon_0$. Since each $H(i)$ is a recursive theory, $\textrm{Con}(H(i))$ is a $\Pi_1^0$-sentence, and by proposition 2.24 from Rathjen's "[The Realm of Ordinal Analysis](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/realm.pdf)", we have $\vert\textrm{PA+}\phi\vert_{sup}=\varepsilon_0$ where $\phi$ is any true arithmetical sentence. So we have $\vert\textrm{PA}\vert_{sup}=\vert \textrm{PA+Con}(H(i))\vert_{sup}$ for all $i<\omega$, and all those proof-theoretic ordinals are $\varepsilon_0$.

This doesn't fully answer the original question though, which was framed in terms of $\vert G(i)\vert_{Con}$ instead of $\vert H(i)\vert_{sup}$. The next step to answering the main question is utilizing this result to compare $\vert H(i)\vert_{Con}$, which also gives us that $\vert H(i)\vert_{Con}=\varepsilon_0$ for all $i<\omega$. (I can provide proof of this fact.)

However, failure to replicate this result for the hierarchy $G(i)$ shows the discrepancy between Mathobi's points: while for all $i<\omega$ we have $\vert H(i)\vert_{Con}=\vert H(i+1)\vert_{Con}$, in contrast we have $\vert G(i)\vert_{Con}<\vert G(i+1)\vert_{Con}$! (This is because otherwise $G(i+1)=\textrm{PRA+TI}(\vert G(i)\vert_{Con})=\textrm{PRA+TI}(\vert G(i+1)\vert_{Con})$ would prove its own consistency.) As a result $\textrm{PRA+TI}(\varepsilon_0)$ is quite a bit stronger than PA+Con(PA) at least in terms of $\vert\, .\,\vert_{Con}$.

Comment: C7X, you got my vote. A for a comment, give me some time to process your answer, and then I will add my reaction as an addendum to my post